# Android custom layout broken when opening in popup

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

So I made a custom layout which I want to use in a popup when a user clicks on an icon. This is what my layout looks like:

[image]

and here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
    android:id="@+id/popupMainLayout">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/icon_drawing_preview_rectangle"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:id="@+id/previewIcon">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:id="@+id/infoTitle"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

            <com.example.app.TouchImageView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:id="@+id/infoPic"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />

        </LinearLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:id="@+id/ivCopy"
        android:background="@drawable/copy"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/relativeLayout" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:id="@+id/ivEdit"
        android:background="@drawable/edit"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ivCopy"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:id="@+id/ivDelete"
        android:background="@drawable/delete"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ivEdit"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/relativeLayout" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:id="@+id/ivPaste"
        android:background="@drawable/paste"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ivCopy"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/ivCopy" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:id="@+id/ivRotate"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ivPaste"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/rotate" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:id="@+id/ivCut"
        android:background="@drawable/cut"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/relativeLayout" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="Cancel"
        android:id="@+id/dismiss"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_buttons"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ivRotate"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

However when I click on my icon my layout gets broken and icons don't line up. This is what it ends up looking like:
[image]

Any particular reason it does this?

**EDIT**:how I launch my popup window:

```
 //inflate our popup layout, set the title and set the icon
                    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_info_layout, null);

                    setOperationsClicklisteners(popupView);//only setting imageview click listeners here

                    TextView title = (TextView)popupView.findViewById(R.id.infoTitle);

                    title.setText(ic.getName());
                    ImageView popupIcon = (ImageView)popupView.findViewById(R.id.infoPic);

                    popupWindow = new PopupWindow(
                            popupView,
                            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                    Button btnDismiss = (Button)popupView.findViewById(R.id.dismiss);
                    btnDismiss.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v)
                        {
                            popupWindow.dismiss();
                        }
                    });

                    popupWindow.setClippingEnabled(true);
                    popupWindow.showAtLocation (v, Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
```

Comment: I think it is due to layout params. In xml it is fill parent but in java code it is wrap_content

Comment: yup I think you are correct, I just switched width/height to wrap_content in my design and it did the exact same thing.

Comment: For your @+id/ivPaste I do not see android:layout_below definition? I see you use alignLeft and alignStart but Start AFAIK is used instead of left (or right if different orientation is in use).

Comment: please show your `onMeasure` and `onLayout` methods if it's a custom layout.

Comment: try creating your popup layout using hardcoded width. That way you will be able to do it correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the comments and suggested answer, I merged them all together and got it working. Main problem as @Vivek Mishra suggested was that my layout width/height was set to `fill_parent` and in my code I inflate it using `wrap_content`.

my new style that works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="360dp"
    android:layout_height="340dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
    android:id="@+id/popupMainLayout">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/icon_drawing_preview_rectangle"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:id="@+id/previewIcon">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:id="@+id/infoTitle"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

            <com.example.app.TouchImageView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:id="@+id/infoPic"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />

        </LinearLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:id="@+id/ivCopy"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:src="@drawable/copy" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:id="@+id/ivEdit"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ivDelete"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/edit" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:id="@+id/ivDelete"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:src="@drawable/delete" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:id="@+id/ivPaste"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ivCopy"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ivCopy"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/ivCopy"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/paste" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:id="@+id/ivRotate"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ivPaste"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ivEdit"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/ivEdit"
        android:src="@drawable/rotate" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:id="@+id/ivCut"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ivRotate"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ivDelete"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/ivDelete"
        android:src="@drawable/cut" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="cancel"
        android:id="@+id/dismiss"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_buttons" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Your layout seems to be wrong.
2. You should use `src` for ImageView icons and not `background`.

   ```
   <RelativeLayout
       android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">
       <ImageView
           src="@drawable/copy"
           android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
           android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
       <ImageView
           src="@drawable/edit"
           android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
           android:layout_centerhorizontal ="true"/>
       <ImageView
           src="@drawable/delete"
           android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
           android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
       <ImageView
           src="@drawable/paste"
           android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
           android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
       <ImageView
           src="@drawable/rotate"
           android:layout_alignTop="@+id/paste"
           android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
       <ImageView
           src="@drawable/cut"
           android:layout_alignTop="@+id/paste"
           android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
       <Button
           android:layout_below="@+id/rotate"
           android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
   </RelativeLayout>
   ```

Comment: I've included your suggestion by changing background to src. However the problem was as @Vivek Mishra suggested. In my code I used wrap_content so I changed it and it seems to work